# Wrap text in file on ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep, uniq

I have 2 text files

```
$ cat com.txt
user1@myskype.com
user3@myskype.net
user5@myskype.net
user4@myskype.net
user2@myskype.net

$ cat net.txt
user1@myskype.net
user3@myskype.net
user5@myskype.net
user2@myskype.net
user4@myskype.net
```

now i would like to read 2 text files and wrap the matching username in format like

```
user1@myskype.net : user1@myskype.com
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one-liner:

```
awk -F'@' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a{print a[$1]" : "$0}' net.txt com.txt
```

Comment: @KevinNguyen: I deleted my answer because it's no longer appropriate because the two 'real' files don't have the same number of users in them. What would you like to happen when the usernames don't match up?

Comment: @KevinNguyen the pastebin link I cannot open... can you paste it in your question?

Comment: @Kent Can you check it back? Thanks!

Comment: @steve IF the username don't match, then we do nothing. I just want the matching ones.

Comment: @Kent Nevermind. Thank you so much for your awesome awk command. It works for me. Cheers